# NSValueTransformer, how to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsvaluetransformer

I am using `NSValueTransformer` class to transform a `NSDictionary` object to custom object.

I have already implemented the subclass with the methods:

```
+ (Class)transformedValueClass
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
```

Then I have registered my subclass with:

```
[NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:[[ClassNameTransformer alloc] init] forName:ClassNameTransformerName];
```

How I am supposed now to get my custom object from a `NSDictionary`. Since I have not found any info about this, only when used with bindings like in `CoreData` and `.xib` files.

Can I use `NSValueTransformer` for my purpose? -> Transform `NSDictionary` into my custom Object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can use `NSValueTransformer` stand-alone

```
ClassNameTransformer *transformer = [[ClassNameTransformer alloc] init];
MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[transformer transformedValue:dictionary];
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is supposed to be used more with binding like using CoreData or xib files. I wonder now if it is not better to use a custom initializer in MyObject with the NSDictionary as parameter.

Comment: Yes, the main purpose is indeed to be used with bindings. The class is actually not needed for just calling the `transformedValue` method.